# Python + BeautifulSoup - Limiting text extraction on a specific table (multiple tables on a webpage)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello all…I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to pick up the content of “Date of Employment:” on a webpage. the webpage contains 5 tables. the 5 tables are similar and looked like below.

```
    <table class="table1"><thead><tr><th style="width: 140px;" class="CII">Design Team</th><th class="top"><a href="#top">Top</a></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="width:20px;">Designer:</td><td>Michael Linnen</td></tr>
            <tr><td style="width:20px;">Date of Employment:</td><td>07 Jan 2012</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="width:20px;">No of Works:</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="width: 15px">No of teams:</td><td vAlign="top">2<br>Combined</td></tr>
```

```
<table class="table1"><thead><tr><th style="width: 140px;" class="CII">Operation Team</th><th class="top"><a href="#top">Top</a></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="width:20px;">Manager:</td><td>Nich Sharmen</td></tr>
            <tr><td style="width:20px;">Date of Employment:</td><td>02 Nov 2005</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="width:20px;">Zones:</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="width: 15px">No of teams:</td><td vAlign="top">2<br>Combined</td></tr>
```

The texts I want is in the 3rd table, the table header is **"Design Team"**.

I am Using below:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

aa = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Date of Employment:"))
bb = aa[2].findNext('td')
print bb.text
```

the problem is that, the “Date of Employment:” in this table sometimes is not available. when it's not there, the code picks the "Date of Employment:" in the next table.

How do I restrict my code to pick only the wanted ones in the table named **“Design Team”**? thanks.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear

Comment: why have you just posted 2 tables?

Comment: because structure wise, they are all similar, so I just pick 2.

Comment: similar or same? :-) This question does matter for the case

Comment: similar. table header/title is different.

Comment: So check for the header and see if the header/title comes from the desired table or not

Comment: Could you please share the URL you are using?

Comment: hi, and thanks alecxe. sorry it's a company internal page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than finding all the `Date of Employment` and finding the next `td` you can directy find the 5th table, given that the `th` is `Design Team`

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

aa = soup.find_all(text="Design Team")

nexttr = aa.next_sibling

if nexttr.td.text == "Date of Employment:":
     print nexttr.td.next_sibling.text 
else:
     print "No Date of Employment:"
```

`nexttr = aa.next_sibling`  finds the next `tr` tag within the `table` tag.

`if nexttr.td.text == "Date of Employment:":` ensures that the text within the next `td`  tag withn the `tr` is `"No Date of Employment:"`

`nexttr.td.next_sibling` extracts the immediate `td` tag following the `"Date of Employment"`

`print nexttr.td.next_sibling.text`  prints the date

Comment: @MarkK you are always welcome. glad to hear it helped :)